# Pandas merge TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm experimenting with pandas merge left_on and right_on params.
According to [Documentation 1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [Documentation 2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Documentation 1: states that left_on and right_on are field names to join on in left/right DataFrame.
Documentation 2: Columns from the left DataFrame to use as **keys**

What does **keys** means?

Following documentation 1:

```
left_frame = pd.DataFrame({'key': range(5),
                       'left_value': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
right_frame = pd.DataFrame({'key': range(2,7),
                       'right_value': ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']})
```

I did this:

```
df = pd.merge(left_frame,right_frame,how='right',right_on='key')
```

left_frame has 'key' as field name, but yet it returns

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df = pd.merge(left_frame, right_frame, how='right', on='key')
```

because same left and right column names.

If columns names are different:

```
df = pd.merge(left_frame, right_frame, how='right', right_on='key1', left_on='key2')
```

> What does **keys** means?

If check [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

> **on** : label or list
>
> Field names to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes, then it merges on the intersection of the columns by default.

And it means values in columns to join on.

Comment: Yes, or need `right_on='key'` with `left_index=True`.

Comment: But then need `index` values for match in left df, so need `df = pd.merge(left_frame.set_index('key'),right_frame, how='right', right_on='key', left_index=True)`

Comment: can I say that left_on and right_on is meant for merging dfs which both have a same column but with different column names?